# Android studio project could not find android.view.View

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

My Android project show that it is not able to find the `android.view.View` class but still it is being compiled and run on simulator and devices.
apart from `android.view.View` All other class of the package is accessible like

This is not available ==> `import android.view.View;`
this is available => `import android.view.ViewGroup;`

I have tried many things like Clean, Rebuild, restart and Invalidate cache and restart but not fixed this issue.

[image]

Please check the code and help me to fix this issue.

```
import android.view.View;

public class AppSettingsActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdListener {

    //Other objects
    private static final String TAG = AppSettingsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    //Data objects

    //    //Design
    private LinearLayout banner_container;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {


        //Actionbar init
        //Action bar
        TextView idTvTitle = findViewById(R.id.idTvTitle);

        findViewById(R.id.idTvSelectDefaultActivity).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.idTvSelectAppLang).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.idIvBack).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.idTvCalcSetting).setOnClickListener(this);

        //Set data
        //Set Actionbar Title
        idTvTitle.setText(R.string.app_settings_text);

        //Load Facebook ads
        banner_container = findViewById(R.id.banner_container);
        if (fbAdView != null) {
            banner_container.addView(fbAdView);
            fbAdView.loadAd();
            fbAdView.setAdListener(this);
            logs.e(TAG, "Face book load add called....");
        }

        int selectedLanguage=SessionManagement.getIntValue(AppSettingsActivity.this, AppConstant.SELECTED_LANG, AppConstant.INT_ONE);
        int selectedScreen=SessionManagement.getIntValue(AppSettingsActivity.this, AppConstant.DEFAULT_SCREEN_INDEX, AppConstant.INT_ONE);
        String[] languages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language);
        String[] screens = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.screens);

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.idTvSelectDefaultActivity)).setText(screens[selectedScreen]);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.idTvSelectAppLang)).setText(languages[selectedLanguage]);
    }
```

Comment: add some more code of the class you are trying to fix for better understanding.

Comment: Hello @Touhidul, I have added more code so you have a better understanding of the situation.

Comment: I reviewed the code. found absolute no reason for the occurrence. weird bug. you can try to migrate to andoirdX if not already, just throwing stone in the dark

Comment: It happens with version 4.1.3 (March 10 2021 build) as well.

Comment: I installed this archived version `Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Canary 13` and it starts working. https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Answer (score 0):

I am giving this answer to my question.

I simply uninstall the Android studio and reinstall it. My previous Android studio was running with 3.5 version (Latest) and the fresh install Android studio version was also 3.5 so there was no versioning difference in it.  But I don't know some How issue fixed when I reinstall AS.

After half an hour of searching, I could not found a solution that can fix my issue. Then I pass the same code to other PC and it was working well on that PC.

So This is final that no issue in the source code.
Then 2nd suspect is the android studio

I uninstall Android Studio and install it again, it took me 1 hour to set-up and make the code workable but it saves 30GB of my hard disk space so it was worth it.

But still, Android studio manage SDK and build tools very badly